# Add stop to setInterval on hover via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS:

```
setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
```

HTML:

```
<a href="site.html" class="gallery form_click">click.</a>
```

I want when hover on `a` button, stop setInterval.

How can I do it?

UPDATED: Thank you for all answers. All soluitons working on static structure. But my `a` tag get via ajax. So, I think must on option. (jQuery version 2.0.3) Right?

Comment: since IDs are unique, also just use "#nextslide"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setinterval id. and later can clearInterval whenever you want to stop executing it.

```
ar refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function(){$("#nextslide").click()}, 10000);

/*On Hover */
$( ".gallery.form_click" ).mouseenter( function(){
clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
})
```

Comment: Checked it not found error. But setInterval is OK, clearInterval crashed.

Comment: Would be great if you can create the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
```

and on hover callback:

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Comment: @user3099199 as i understand u i can't add event listener to `a` after it added by ajax? just use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) handler to handle `hover` event...

Comment: .live handler on jQuery 2?

Comment: @user3099199 `$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+` from link above

Comment: @Kirill .live() is not supported with latest jquery so use on()

Answer (score 0):

`clearInterval()` is used to stop the interval.

Use event delegation as `a` is appended dynamically.

Write:

```
var t = setInterval(function () {
    $("#nav #nextslide").click()
}, 10000);
$(document).on("hover","a",(function () {
    clearInterval(t);
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/QmEXS/1)

Answer (score 0):

try hover-in and hover-out function on your anchor tag, make your interval global so it can be stop and start:

```
var interval=setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
$( ".gallery" ).hover(
  function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
  }, function() {
     interval = setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
  }
);
```

if a tag is dynamic then use [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
var interval=setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
$( ".gallery" ).on(
  mouseenter: function() {
      clearInterval(interval);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
     interval = setInterval(function(){ $("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
  }
);
```

and for only stop on hover:

```
$('.gallery').on("hover",(function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
});
```

Comment: Where do you start the animation here

Comment: starting animation would be same on document ready, or if any trigger to start

Comment: In your example you are repeating code to start. Either have a reusable function or trigger hover

Answer (score 0):

Just give the interval function a name so you can refer to it later with .clearInterval.

Start interval function:

```
nameOfIntervalFunction = setInterval(function(){$("#nav #nextslide").click()},10000);
```

Stop interval function with hover:

```
$( "a.gallery.form_click" ).mouseenter( function(){
    window.clearInterval(nameOfIntervalFunction)
})
```